# How to get unmatching data from 2 dataframes based on one column. (Pandas)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames sample output is here 
[image: first Dataframe]
[image: Second dataframe]
My code for getting those and formatting the date column is here

First df:

`csv_data_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_to_data+'\\Data\\',appendedfile))
csv_data_df['Date_Formatted'] = pd.to_datetime(csv_data_df['DATE']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
csv_data_df.head(3)`

second df :

```
new_Data_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))
new_Data_df['Date_Formatted'] = 
pd.to_datetime(new_Data_df['DATE']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
new_Data_df.head(3)`
```

I want to construct third dataframe where only the rows with un-matching dates from second dataframe needs to go in third one. 
Is there any method to do that. The date formatted column you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This should be a fairly simple solution to implement in Pandas.

Comment: @VictorC.currently i am tried it by reading dates and check if incoming dates are greater than max date of previous file . I wanted to know that is there any join method to do this

Comment: Try reading through this link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html The first couple functions should be enough. Please let me know if you have any problems with it!

Comment: @VictorC. I can use this from the link u provided                     `pd.concat(objs, axis=0, join='outer', join_axes=None, ignore_index=False,
  keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False,
  copy=True)` . But it is directly joining all the entries from second frame to first one. I only want outmatching entries. I want to match date column only

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want to do. It seems from your question you wanted to simply join the first and second dataframes without repeating any entries. Is that what you aim to do? If not, can you provide an example of what you want to do or some sample output for a third dataframe so it is clearer?

Comment: @VictorC. well i only want those rows from second dataframe where dates dosent match with dates of first dataframe .

Answer (score 1):

You could set the index of both dataframes to your desired join column, then
use [`df1.combine_first(df2)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html). For your specific example here, that could look like the below line.

```
csv_data_df.set_index('Date_Formatted').combine_first(new_Data_df.set_index('Date_Formatted')).reset_index()
```

Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('abc'), index=list(range(1, 6)))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns=list('abc'))

df
Out[10]: 
          a         b         c
1 -1.357517 -0.925239  0.974483
2  0.362472 -1.881582  1.263237
3  0.785508  0.227835 -0.604377
4 -0.386585 -0.511583  3.080297
5  0.660516 -1.393421  1.363900

df2
Out[11]: 
          a         b         c
0  1.732251 -1.977803  0.720292
1  0.048229  1.125277  1.016083
2 -1.684013  2.136061  0.553824
3 -0.022957  1.237249  0.236923
4 -0.998079  1.714126  1.291391
5  0.955464 -0.049673  1.629146
6  0.865864  1.137120  1.117207
7 -0.126944  1.003784 -0.180811

df.combine_first(df2)
Out[13]: 
          a         b         c
0  1.732251 -1.977803  0.720292
1 -1.357517 -0.925239  0.974483
2  0.362472 -1.881582  1.263237
3  0.785508  0.227835 -0.604377
4 -0.386585 -0.511583  3.080297
5  0.660516 -1.393421  1.363900
6  0.865864  1.137120  1.117207
7 -0.126944  1.003784 -0.180811
```

Comment: well i only want those rows from second dataframe where dates dosent match with dates of first dataframe .

Comment: @PriyalChaudhari That is what this does. Edited with example.